# Did Muhammed al-Arifi issue a fatwa permitting rape of Syrian women?

Tags: islam, sexual-abuse, syria

[Taslima Nasrin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taslima_Nasrin) claimed in her [blog](http://freethoughtblogs.com/taslima/2012/12/31/a-fatwa-to-rape/) that Saudi cleric Mohammed al-Arifi issued "a fatawa to rape!". She quoted the following excerpt from this [liveleak post](http://www.liveleak.com/view?i=bbc_1356790017) as evidence.

> A Wahhabi religious cleric in Saudi Arabia, Muhammed al-Arifi, who is
>   very influential in Jihadi circles, has recently issued a fatwa
>   (religious edict) that permits all Jihadist militants in Syria to
>   engage in short-lived marriages with Syrian women that each lasts for
>   a few hours in order to satisfy their sexual desires and boost their
>   determination in killing Syrians. He called the marriage as
>   ‘intercourse marriage’. It requires that the Syrian female be at least
>   14 years old, widowed, or divorced.

Is it true or false?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### It's fake.

Electronicintifada.net reports:

> The claim about the “fatwa” was made on Lebanon’s Al-Jadeed channel
>   (New TV) at least as early as **December 29.** Al-Jadeed does not provide
>   any evidence of the “fatwa” or say when, where or by what means it was
>   supposedly issued. As of now, no one has produced any evidence that
>   the “fatwa” exists, which means that no responsible news organization
>   should behave as if it does.
>
> News of the “fatwa” was then disseminated widely on social media in
>   Arabic, particularly by personas eager to discredit opponents of the
>   Syrian government.

After that, Iran's English-language based Press TV published a [report](http://www.presstv.ir/detail/2012/12/31/280993/militants-can-marry-syrian-women/) citing Al-Jadeed channel:

> Iran’s English-language Press TV carried a report on the alleged fatwa
>   on its website. However it is not the Iranian report that appears to
>   have been the most influential.

The original video of Al Jadeed channel was edited and posted on youtube ([link](https://youtu.be/6Qvo4_hMrF4)) by a Syrian pro goverment twitter user:

> **Effort to discredit Syrian opposition**
>
> On 29 December a Twitter user
>   called @Eretz_Zen tweeted the New TV video except now with English
>   subtitles and a logo with the words “Eretz Zen” obscuring the New TV
>   logo.
>
> Twitter user @Eretz_Zen’s bio claims to be “A secular Syrian opposed
>   to having my country turned into a Taliban-like state.” This is of
>   course completely unverifiable

On 1 January, RadicalIslam.org (a website run by clarion project) forwarded the report ([Link](http://web.archive.org/web/20130104101848/http://www.radicalislam.org/news/saudi-cleric-issues-fatwa-allowing-gang-rape-syrian-women)):

> **Zionist and Islamophobic connections**
>
> On 1 January the English-subtitled “Eretz Zen” video was embedded in a
>   report on the website RadicalIslam.org with the headline “Cleric
>   Issues Fatwa Allowing Gang Rape of Syrian Women.”
>
> RadicalIslam.org states that it is supported by the Clarion Fund,
>   which several years ago distributed tens of millions of copies of a
>   virulently anti-Muslim film titled Obsession: Radical Islam’s War
>   Against the West.
>
> As Ali Gharib and Eli Clifton reported, Clarion Fund is closely tied
>   to the Israeli organization Aish HaTorah, and the group is at the
>   center of a web of ultra far-right Islamophobic, Zionist and
>   anti-Palestinian organizations. One of its “advisors” has been
>   notorious anti-Islamic and anti-Palestinian agitator Daniel Pipes.
>
> Another key figure in this anti-Palestinian and Islamophobic network
>   is Frank Gaffney, another Clarion Fund advisor. Gaffney’s Center for
>   Security Policy sponsors Latma TV, an Israeli “satirical” show
>   responsible for producing virulently anti-African propaganda and
>   disseminating the Norway “rape epidemic” hoax.

The report then appeared in [Alternet.org](http://www.alternet.org/world/saudi-religious-leader-accused-calling-gang-rape-syrian-women-issues-denial) and Salon.com. On January 2, Alternet admitted it's false and posted an apology:

> AlterNet has posted an apology and analysis of the story’s origins.
>
> On January 2, AlterNet was one of several outlets that published what
>   turned out to be an article based on a false report. We would like to
>   apologize to our readers for the error.

Salon also deleted the article:

> At approximately 15:30 UTC on 3 January 2013, Salon deleted their
>   story which was sourced from AlterNet.
>
> [Primary Source, Electronicintifada.net](https://electronicintifada.net/blogs/ali-abunimah/how-progressive-alternet-and-salon-fell-gang-rape-fatwa-peddled-islamophobes)

Huffingtonpost writes:

> ... the fatwa was fabricated and widely disseminated by the Syrian regime
>   and its allies, namely Hezbollah and Iran, to send a twofold message.
>   The first one is directed to the Syrian conservative community with
>   the aim of tarnishing and stigmatizing the jihadist rebels, who
>   allegedly authorized prostitution in the garb of temporary marriages.
>
> The second message is to the international community to lose faith in
>   the FSA, which mainly comes from Syria’s Sunni majority, and to
>   question its ability to build a free democratic Syria.
>
> [Source](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/hilmi-m-zawati/sectarian-war-in-syria-in_b_9236606.html)

---

Comment: +1 for citing electronicintifada.net over the other trash first.

Comment: @EvanCarroll The facebook msg I sent you or the comment on your answer?